# Custom directive not binding correctly in ng-if second time around

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a custom directive which is using two way binding to my controller (using '=').

```
<my-streetview 
    latitude="quickView.streetView.latitude" 
    longitude="quickView.streetView.longitude" 
    ng-if="quickView.activeTab === 'street'"
></my-streetview>
```

I'm using ng-if because I don't wnt the google map/streetview being loaded until the tab which it is in is opened. The trouble is that the first time it shows everything works but the second time the ng-if is true (when you click a different tab then come back to the tab) it seems to set the long and lat to undefined.

I know the following:

A) if I change ng-hide to ng-show it just works. The google map is not being destroyed and created every time you leave nad return to the tab so this makes sense. It's something to do with ng-if destroying something when it's false I think.

B) The lat and long values DO actually get changed in the parent controller because I put a $watch and a console.log() in there to test it. Basically when the ng-if is set to true the first time it creates the streetview fine, the second and subsequent times it either cannot read the values from the parent controller, or is actually setting them to undefinied.

C) Nothing else is different between the first time the ng-if is shown and subsequent times. There is no other code I can think of coming into play.

Any ideas would really be appreciated.

Here is my full code for my street view directive.

```
angular.module('my.directives')

.constant('myStreetviewDefaults', {

    latitude: 51.816102,
    longitude: -0.811619

})


.directive('myStreetview', function ($timeout, myStreetviewDefaults) {

    return {

        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            latitude: '=',
            longitude: '='
        },


        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {

            $scope.latitude = angular.isDefined($scope.latitude) ? $scope.$eval($scope.latitude) : myStreetviewDefaults.latitude;
            $scope.longitude = angular.isDefined($scope.longitude) ? $scope.$eval($scope.longitude) : myStreetviewDefaults.longitude;


            // Create the panorama
            var mapEl = $('<my-streetview-map></my-streetview-map>');
            mapEl.addClass('my-streetview-map-container');


            $element.append(mapEl);

            var panorama = new google.maps.StreetViewPanorama(mapEl[0], {
                position: {
                    lat: $scope.latitude,
                    lng: $scope.longitude
                },
                pov: {
                    heading: 34,
                    pitch: 10
                }
            });


            // Watch latitude and longitude to reset the center
            $scope.$watchGroup(['latitude','longitude'], function (newValues, oldValues, $scope) {

                panorama.setPosition({
                    lat: $scope.latitude,
                    lng: $scope.longitude
                });

            });


            // Hack to get street view drawing properly on second load
            // https://github.com/allenhwkim/angularjs-google-maps/issues/59
            $timeout(function(){
                google.maps.event.trigger(panorama,'resize'); 
            }, 100);

        }


    };


});
```

This is the controller code for the Angular UI modal that the streetview sits inside.

```
angular.module('app')

.controller('QuickViewCtrl', function ($rootScope, $scope, $log, $http, appConfig, $u, $modalInstance, modalSettings) {

    'use strict';

    var master = $scope.master;

    var quickView = this;


    $log.info('Quick View Opened', modalSettings);


    this.close = function(){
        $modalInstance.close();
    }

    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    //  Initialize Page
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

    var init = function () {

        // Set the initial tab
        quickView.activeTab = modalSettings.initialPanel;


        // Set up the street view
        quickView.streetView = {
            latitude: modalSettings.property.latitude,
            longitude: modalSettings.property.longitude
        };


        $scope.$watch('quickView.streetView', function(newValues, oldValues){
            console.log("Test watching from controller", newValues);
        }, true);



    };

    init();

});
```

And this is the template for the modal window....

```
<div class="quickView modal-inner modal--has-header modal--has-footer">

    <!-- Header -->
    <div class="modal-header">

        <!-- Header removed for brevity -->

    </div>
    <div class="modal-main">

        <!-- Tabs -->
        <my-tabset
            my-tabset-active-tab="quickView.activeTab" 
        >
            <div my-tabset-tabs my-tabset-tabs--equal4>
                <a href="#" my-tabset-tab my-tabset-tab-name="overview" is-active="true">
                    <div my-tabset-tab-text>Overview</div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" my-tabset-tab my-tabset-tab-name="gallery">
                    <div my-tabset-tab-text>Gallery</div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" my-tabset-tab my-tabset-tab-name="map">
                    <div my-tabset-tab-text>Map</div>
                </a>
                <a href="#" my-tabset-tab my-tabset-tab-name="street">
                    <div my-tabset-tab-text>Street View</div>
                </a>
            </div>
            <div my-tabset-panels>

                <!-- Overview Panel -->
                <div my-tabset-panel my-tabset-tab-name="overview" is-active="true">

                    <div ng-if="quickView.activeTab === 'overview'">

                        <!-- Overview removed for brevity -->

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Gallery Panel -->
                <div my-tabset-panel my-tabset-tab-name="gallery">

                    <div ng-if="quickView.activeTab === 'gallery'">

                        <!-- Gallery removed for brevity -->

                    </div>

                </div>

                <!-- Map Panel -->
                <div my-tabset-panel my-tabset-tab-name="map">

                    <ui-gmap-google-map 
                        center='quickView.map.center' 
                        zoom='quickView.map.zoom' 
                        options="quickView.map.options" 
                        control="quickView.mapControl" 
                        ng-if="quickView.activeTab === 'map'"
                    >
                        <ui-gmap-marker
                            idKey="'quickViewMapMarker'" 
                            coords='quickView.map.markerPosition'
                        >
                        </ui-gmap-marker>
                    </ui-gmap-google-map>

                </div>

                <!-- Street View Panel -->
                <div my-tabset-panel my-tabset-tab-name="street">

                    <my-streetview 
                        latitude="quickView.streetView.latitude" 
                        longitude="quickView.streetView.longitude" 
                        ng-if="quickView.activeTab === 'street'"
                    ></my-streetview>

                </div>
            </div>
        </my-tabset>

    </div>


    <!-- Footer -->
    <div class="modal-footer">
        Footer
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Does your directive update the values for lat and long in any way?  If so, that might be your problem, as ng-if creates a child scope, with copies of the parent scope values. If the directive is changing the values, then I believe it will be the child values, and the parent values then become out of sync.

Comment: Well, I am using two way binding in the isolate scope .......... scope: { latitude: '=',longitude: '='} .......... However, I would understand if the isolate scope created by ng-if was stopping the parent from being updated, it's the fact that it IS being updated to undefined that I can't get my head around. maybe I just don't understand Angular scope at all.

Comment: I can't think of an alternative to ng-if either. Even an ng-include would run straight away and load all the maps before they are needed.

Comment: *... and let the guessing games begin.* Although it may be fun, this isn't really a good use of our collective time to guess what the problem might be based on your symptoms. Yes, it's likely the child scope created by `ng-if` - bind against an object property rather than directly to a property of the scope... but more so, **show relevant code**

Comment: @jonhobbs, brusque perhaps, hardly rude. Never mind about the "bind against property of an object..." - looks like you are already doing this, so it isn't *that*

Comment: The main thing I don't understand is that if ng-if creates an isolate scope and that stops any directives inside it from 2 way binding to any of it's parents (in this case my page controller) then how do other directives get round this. How come I can nest an ng-repeat inside an ng-if and bind the ng-repeat to my control which is further up the scope chain. I assume the guys that wrote angular-ui-maps got round this somehow because I have that inside an ngId and all my map settings are bound to my page controller.

Comment: @jonhobbs, can you show some relevant controller code and the close surroundings of your `<my-streetview>`? illustrative plunker would also help

Comment: Sure, will add that now, although it's not doing much which is why I didn't add it.

Comment: I've just realised in posting that that the streetview sits inside a tabset which is also my own directive and also uses an isolate scope. I don't think this is relevant though because it still works when you remove the ng-if. The very fact that it binds everything correctly the first time would suggest to me that it's not isolate scopes that are causeing the problem because however may directives the streetview is nested inside it obviously has access to the modal controller code which is several 'parents' up the first time it is bound.

Comment: @jonhobbs, when `ng-if` is falsy, it removes the element and its child scope, but when it's true again - it re-links the directive and puts a cloned `<my-streetview>` there, and so a new `<my-streetview-map>`. It should work though, if the directive is always in the scope of the controller. But  `myTabsetPanel` and the modal directives complicate things here - it's not clear whether it transcludes or not. You need to start reducing this complexity but trying simpler things - i.e. without tabs or without modal - to prove that they work

Comment: Thanks, I will try without tabs to start with. I am not using transclusion in my tabset directive though.

Comment: OK, so I removed the tabset completely and set up a simple button which toggled quickView.showMap on and off then I put a div around the streetview with ng-if="quickView.showMap".. The first time I toggle the map on my streetview directive receives the correct lat and long, then if I toggle it off and back on again they both seem to be undefined, in the streetview directive and in the modal controller code as I set up a watch in both those places. The change doesn't happen when it is toggled off, it happens when it is toggled back on for the second time.

Comment: Here's a plunker that sort of reproduces your issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/Mn0uJHh2cQmb4IgDu8Ld?p=preview. The offending line is the `$scope.$eval` one - why is this necessary? Just do $scope.foo = $scope.foo || 'defaultFoo';`

Comment: Thanks, that works in the plunkr but not in my app because the lat and long need do be decimals. I think I got into the habit of using scope.eval on all values passed in via attributes because I ran into problems when passing in boolean values. In this instance lat and I'm getting a Google Maps error now that I've removed scope.eval. I'm not sure why because the default values are decimals and so are the values I'm binding to on the parent controller.Not sure why they're not valid, or why parseFloat isn't making them valid.

Comment: OK, so I've gone back to my original code but replaced $scope.$eval with parseInt() and it seems to work......  $scope.latitude = angular.isDefined($scope.latitude) ? parseFloat($scope.latitude) : myStreetviewDefaults.latitude;  ...... I don't know why eval was causing this problem. I suspect that would require a much deeper understanding of Angular internals, but I'm eternally grateful for the help as I would never have suspected that or found the problem. If you add it as an answer I'l mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The offending lines are:

```
$scope.latitude = angular.isDefined($scope.latitude) ? $scope.$eval($scope.latitude) : myStreetviewDefaults.latitude;
$scope.longitude = angular.isDefined($scope.longitude) ? $scope.$eval($scope.longitude) : myStreetviewDefaults.longitude;
```

It's not clear why you are using `$scope.$eval($scope.latitude)`, but it might stem from a misunderstanding of what `$scope.$eval` does.

`$scope.$eval` takes an expression, for example: `"quickView.streetView.latitude"`, and evaluates it against the `$scope` upon which the `$eval` is called.

You called it with `$scope.latitude` as a parameter, which means the the evaluated expression was something like `35.344542` - clearly not something defined on the scope - and so you got `undefined`.

Perhaps you meant to use `$attrs.latitude` - that would have given you the `"quickView.streetView.latitude"`  expression, but you would have needed to call it on the parent scope, since your directive uses an isolate scope that is not aware of what `quickView` (etc...) is:

```
$scope.$parent.$eval($attrs.latitude)
```

But more so, you don't even need this `$eval` at all, since `$scope.latitude` has already acquired the evaluated value automatically via two-way binding. The following would have worked just as well:

```
$scope.latitude = angular.isDefined($scope.latitude) 
                       ? $scope.latitude 
                       : myStreetviewDefaults.latitude;
```

Comment: Thanks, additionally I just needed to use parseFloat on it because attributes are strings. That's what I thought $scope.eval was doing, I totally misunderstood.

Comment: @jonhobbs, `parseFloat` wouldn't have been needed if they values were numbers to begin with, and not strings